# When does a monowhip count as a whip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter

So I am running a [Steelbound fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/steelbound-fighter-fighter-archetype/) in an Iron Gods campaign who has chosen whips. Assuming I get a monowhip, what, if anything, can I use for the monowhip?  Can I use it as my bonded weapon and/or use the whip specific feats (weapon focus, serpent lash, and others)?

Answer (score 3):

### It counts as a whip when it is activated

From the [weapon's description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons/#TOC-Monowhip):

> A monowhip is a deadly melee weapon capable of inflicting horrible wounds, even in the hands of the weak. An inactive monowhip looks like a short metal baton, but **when it’s activated**, a small weight detaches, revealing a 15-foot-long monofilament length. **Wielded like a whip**, a monowhip slices deeply into targets and can inflict grievous critical hits with shocking ease. Attacks made with a monowhip resolve as touch attacks, and they ignore hardness as if the monofilament were made of adamantine. A monowhip’s damage cannot be enhanced by strength, as the monofilament slices with equal ease regardless of the force applied. Activating a monowhip is a move action; **once activated**, the whip **consumes power** incredibly quickly, **at the rate of 1 charge per round**.

Basically, for all purposes, an *activated* monowhip counts as a whip, for as long as it has charges left.

As for the [Steelbound](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/steelbound-fighter-fighter-archetype/) fighter archetype, you need a bit of *GM Fiat* there. It counts as a whip when it's activated, for all purposes. Otherwise, it's a metal baton and not a whip, which is not a valid target for *Steelbound Awakening*. It's up to the GM to decide if it can be a bonded weapon or not in that situation.

Personally, unless the player is able to find a way to supply it with power indefinitely (which is possible), I would say it's not a valid target for that ability.

For instance, we know that you can install a [Power Generator](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/technological-equipment/technological-artifacts/#TOC-Power-Generators) in a technological weapon. Those generators *yield* a certain number of charges per hour, which can be used to supply any technological gear. Considering that a **Fission Reactor Generator** can supply 1000 charges per hour, and we have 600 rounds of combat per hour, you could use one of those to keep your *Monowhip* supplied with energy 24/7. Then, I would consider it a valid target to become an intelligent weapon.

Comment: I think I understand your conclusion with the steelbound archetype, but i do have one concern about it, your claim that the monowhip is a metal baton when not active. My concern is the wording states that it looks like a baton, and when activated it reveals the whip aspects.  I assume that is something you already took into consideration when writing this. I just have concerns about how that line of thinking affects other weapons that don't look like weapons until used.

Comment: I suppose there is another possible issue.  If i had picked, for some awful reason, a monowhip as my bonded weapon, would I need to keep it active 24/7 to bond with it or is that only because it only counts as a whip when wielding it?  If i can't bond with it even choosing monowhip because it needs to be active, does that mean i cannot bond with a gun or bow unless they are ready to fire 24/7?

Comment: @shuffy if your weapon of choice at first level, from *Weapon Focus*, was "steel baton", then sure, it could be your bonded weapon while not activated. But ultimately, this all seems like *GM Fiat* to me.

Comment: So if I picked "monowhip" I could only bond with the monowhip if it was active 24/7? I would need to pick "steel baton" to bond with an inactive monowhip? That doesn't seem right to me.  It seems like that would mean an unloaded gun isn't a gun, or a magic staff is only a magic staff when you are casting a spell from it.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to consult your GM.

Comment: i already have an answer from my gm, from before i even asked the question.  i felt that it was a question that should atleast be asked on here though.

Answer (score 0):

### A monowhip counts as a whip as a weapon

According to the general rule of [technological weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons/):

> If an existing weapon proficiency allows the new weapon’s use, that weapon proficiency is listed in parentheses.

The monowhip entry has Proficiency exotic (whip) listed, so it is considered a whip whenever a whip is needed as a weapon. So most feats and class abilities will consider a monowhip a whip.

Depending on your GM a monowhip might not be able to be used for more utility things, such as grabbing small items. This is not because it isn't a whip, but because:

> A monowhip’s damage cannot be enhanced by strength, as the monofilament slices with equal ease regardless of the force applied.

As a result you will probably still want to keep a non-monowhip around.